# Refresh and show updated data on Standard related list from Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, related-list, redirect, refresh

I have a custom lightning component which resides on a different page than the standard record detail page in Lightning view.
When the custom component opens up, it show a list of products which I choose and add to the Opportunity.
When I save and redirect to the Opportunity record detail page, I'm not able to view the products added from the component.
I have to again refresh the opportunity page to show the list on the Product related list.

What should I do to show the products added without refreshing the page again?

Comment: Do you have any override of edit button on Opportunity and are you using force:navigateToSObject to navigate to the Opportunity page after adding products?

Comment: @JayantDas, when my processing is complete I use force:navigateToSObject

Comment: You may like to take a look at this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCpKQAU) with force:navigateToSObject, if that's your scenario as well.

Comment: @JayantDas, the problem is somewhat the same but I'm not overriding the edit button but I have a custom detail page button which open a VF page containing a Lightning Component.

Comment: Check this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158003/values-are-not-updated-in-lightning-after-record-update), if this helps.